# Prove the sequence $2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, \ldots$ doesn't tend to $0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here's the definition of null sequence

> $(a_n) \to 0 \iff \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N $ such that $n > N \implies |a_n| <\epsilon.$

reworded as

$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \forall n > N (|a_n| <\epsilon).$

and negated

$ \exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N \exists n > N (|a_n| \ge \epsilon).$

I think we are looking for some $\epsilon > 0$ such that no matter what term in the sequence we point at there's next one whose absolute value is greater or equal to $\epsilon.$ Choosing any $\epsilon$ seems to work fine except for this situation: let $\epsilon > 1, N = 2$ in which case there is $n = 3$ such that $a_n = 0 < \epsilon.$ But I am not sure what values $\epsilon$ is allowed to take. What are the problems in my argument and how can I fix them?

Comment: Let $\epsilon = 1$ Let N be a positive integer. Let $n = N +100$ (there is no need to make $n$ the best $n$). Then $|a_n| \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: ^ It's important to notice that because of the quantifier order, you can choose a different $n$ for each $N$, but $\epsilon$ must be fixed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is fine, and you are right that any $\epsilon$ will work, but you really only need to choose one $\epsilon$.  So you can formalize as follows:

Let $\epsilon = 1$.  Given any $N$, let $n = \max\left\{5, N+1\right\}$.  Then $|a_n| > \epsilon$.  Notice that you could have chosen any $\epsilon > 0$ with essentially the same argument.

Comment: So long as our argument works for infinite number of terms, it doesn't matter if there's a finite number of terms who contradict our argument. Is that correct?

Comment: Right, as long as you choose $n$ large enough, you will avoid that finite number of terms.